# Robotium : Use in a third-party project

Tags: android, robotium, android-library

As I'm doing some unit test on Android, I usually use [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/).

The core of this tool is really powerful but I made some helper classes and I would like to export them in a separate project so I can re-use them in all my projects.

So I created a new Android Studio library project in order to put my classes inside.

My `build.gradle` is like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium:5.3.1'
}
```

And my classes are under my package (*modoule/src/main/java/package/*).

The thing is, my classes are using some Robotium objects (like `Solo`) and my project can't resolve the `import com.robotium.solo.Solo;`

I'm stuck on that. The goal is not to do unit test, but to do a kind of plug-in for `Robotium` that I will use in my projects by adding this to their `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium:5.3.1'
    androidTestCompile 'mytools:module:version'
}
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the object Solo can't be access in the scope "compile".

You can use the following dependency in replacement:

```
dependencies { 
     compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.3.1'
}
```

Enjoy :)